Can't connect MariaDB tp images with Docker Desktop
I was trying to build a quick flarum and config a database to it in docker. MariaDB was running well, but when I try to connect it to my flarum container, it doesn't connect.
mariaDB images :
https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb?uuid=B237E203-2CDD-49E9-8D1A-B30B70EC1210
flarum images:
https://hub.docker.com/r/crazymax/flarum?uuid=B237E203-2CDD-49E9-8D1A-B30B70EC1210
flarum inspect
{
    "Id": "fd366b654eb11fc5e37e770516778af8770ec538f4f4b1717139d5387ff6eddc",
    "Created": "2024-12-15T03:17:08.336499287Z",
    "Path": "/init",
    "Args": [],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 1256,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2024-12-17T07:54:37.022018114Z",
        "FinishedAt": "2024-12-17T07:52:14.975669748Z"
    },
    "Image": "sha256:6282d2ccbb59143388e0508315b1e265d4c0557820d706d0a0f80d4645cf01f3",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/fd366b654eb11fc5e37e770516778af8770ec538f4f4b1717139d5387ff6eddc/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/fd366b654eb11fc5e37e770516778af8770ec538f4f4b1717139d5387ff6eddc/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/fd366b654eb11fc5e37e770516778af8770ec538f4f4b1717139d5387ff6eddc/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/fd366b654eb11fc5e37e770516778af8770ec538f4f4b1717139d5387ff6eddc/fd366b654eb11fc5e37e770516778af8770ec538f4f4b1717139d5387ff6eddc-json.log",
    "Name": "/peaceful_napier",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "overlay2",
    "Platform": "linux",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [],
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "NetworkMode": "bridge",
        "PortBindings": {
            "8000/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "80"
                }
            ]
        },
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "no",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "AutoRemove": false,
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "VolumesFrom": null,
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ],
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "CgroupnsMode": "host",
        "Dns": [],
        "DnsOptions": [],
        "DnsSearch": [],
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "IpcMode": "private",
        "Cgroup": "",
        "Links": null,
        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
        "PidMode": "",
        "Privileged": false,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "UTSMode": "",
        "UsernsMode": "",
        "ShmSize": 67108864,
        "Runtime": "runc",
        "Isolation": "",
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Memory": 0,
        "NanoCpus": 0,
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
        "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "Devices": null,
        "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
        "DeviceRequests": null,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "MemorySwappiness": null,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "PidsLimit": null,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "CpuCount": 0,
        "CpuPercent": 0,
        "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
        "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
        "MaskedPaths": [
            "/proc/asound",
            "/proc/acpi",
            "/proc/kcore",
            "/proc/keys",
            "/proc/latency_stats",
            "/proc/timer_list",
            "/proc/timer_stats",
            "/proc/sched_debug",
            "/proc/scsi",
            "/sys/firmware",
            "/sys/devices/virtual/powercap"
        ],
        "ReadonlyPaths": [
            "/proc/bus",
            "/proc/fs",
            "/proc/irq",
            "/proc/sys",
            "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
        ]
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Data": {
            "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9c2c5e13db418cfa403a3b4b39e544848ceceb8df752829291ce586c7599de50-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/307fa14b7c374cc62f95caae3b7434f5ce90f67b39376e84922081649ab1529e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/55f983ea4a1f7b7ae6344aa9cf631858d9a659ed1856007685fce708c54c2177/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/81e0387eaf08df646e3513e97d65e0792e421fcc6b4f7a4f34227c7a2d5557d5/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/709cc30e5680d8ad6c9d6a66d371efba4b5ef79e7b7fffefd227940fdffebfcd/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f989b05bdad0da9e4bf613aae771a2b19cb6a529a7e362b1a2700a8c322344b8/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/cea3b71c19b10bbb48910abb1fc2f4b7827488e6373a76144039ec8ad0b262e1/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0f319587f60d20d3aba3765063b6928e854e5c2734f54e2f224aee7df179c085/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/841233e945b30f2fc6d7d1037cd0886e0bc0c42fcbd161c1e2550d397fd84768/diff",
            "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9c2c5e13db418cfa403a3b4b39e544848ceceb8df752829291ce586c7599de50/merged",
            "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9c2c5e13db418cfa403a3b4b39e544848ceceb8df752829291ce586c7599de50/diff",
            "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9c2c5e13db418cfa403a3b4b39e544848ceceb8df752829291ce586c7599de50/work"
        },
        "Name": "overlay2"
    },
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "volume",
            "Name": "81a7bd9e051b27567e60f4387e8cb93846a179b35cadd18f6060f36b66d834a8",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/81a7bd9e051b27567e60f4387e8cb93846a179b35cadd18f6060f36b66d834a8/_data",
            "Destination": "/data",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        }
    ],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "fd366b654eb1",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "8000/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "FLARUM_BASE_URL=127.0.0.1:8080",
            "DB_HOST=flarum_db",
            "DB_PASSWORD=flarum_password",
            "DB_USER=flarum_user",
            "DB_NAME=flarum",
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "S6_BEHAVIOUR_IF_STAGE2_FAILS=2",
            "TZ=UTC",
            "PUID=1000",
            "PGID=1000"
        ],
        "Cmd": null,
        "Image": "crazymax/flarum:latest",
        "Volumes": {
            "/data": {}
        },
        "WorkingDir": "/opt/flarum",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "/init"
        ],
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {
            "org.opencontainers.image.created": "2024-11-03T18:14:31.450Z",
            "org.opencontainers.image.description": "Flarum simple forum",
            "org.opencontainers.image.licenses": "MIT",
            "org.opencontainers.image.revision": "3b6fdfedf7bc53ed72092f15588247874ac0597d",
            "org.opencontainers.image.source": "https://github.com/crazy-max/docker-flarum",
            "org.opencontainers.image.title": "Flarum",
            "org.opencontainers.image.url": "https://github.com/crazy-max/docker-flarum",
            "org.opencontainers.image.vendor": "CrazyMax",
            "org.opencontainers.image.version": "1.8.8"
        }
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "e959c325be38f69c5d793b744a05c5154ae7c7a074c94be31186acc4e30882b5",
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/e959c325be38",
        "Ports": {
            "8000/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "80"
                }
            ]
        },
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "58f327c2bb13cb71aa5ca75e6b738cb9ebd409da54e6f3ebc66d1129de54a331",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": null,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "DriverOpts": null,
                "NetworkID": "ca3b0138d767f7cc4262d6ee3e1223c8851c71beb01f2fa225fd4c63c5ba727a",
                "EndpointID": "58f327c2bb13cb71aa5ca75e6b738cb9ebd409da54e6f3ebc66d1129de54a331",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "DNSNames": null
            }
        }
    }
}

mariadb inspect:
{
    "Id": "037e43e31ace1d0a6c4ac98b6bb960e75b3e6d11b1de0e7b6bc08017f27f4959",
    "Created": "2024-12-17T07:52:20.444543215Z",
    "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
    "Args": [
        "mariadbd"
    ],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 1066,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2024-12-17T07:52:20.577152252Z",
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "Image": "sha256:6722945a6940fd6c3e394cb4791057f7210b0ead90eee0f85094cd24e2ca412d",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/037e43e31ace1d0a6c4ac98b6bb960e75b3e6d11b1de0e7b6bc08017f27f4959/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/037e43e31ace1d0a6c4ac98b6bb960e75b3e6d11b1de0e7b6bc08017f27f4959/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/037e43e31ace1d0a6c4ac98b6bb960e75b3e6d11b1de0e7b6bc08017f27f4959/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/037e43e31ace1d0a6c4ac98b6bb960e75b3e6d11b1de0e7b6bc08017f27f4959/037e43e31ace1d0a6c4ac98b6bb960e75b3e6d11b1de0e7b6bc08017f27f4959-json.log",
    "Name": "/flarumdb",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "overlay2",
    "Platform": "linux",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [],
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "NetworkMode": "bridge",
        "PortBindings": {
            "3306/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "3036"
                }
            ]
        },
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "no",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "AutoRemove": false,
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "VolumesFrom": null,
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ],
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "CgroupnsMode": "host",
        "Dns": null,
        "DnsOptions": null,
        "DnsSearch": null,
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "IpcMode": "private",
        "Cgroup": "",
        "Links": null,
        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
        "PidMode": "",
        "Privileged": false,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "UTSMode": "",
        "UsernsMode": "",
        "ShmSize": 67108864,
        "Runtime": "runc",
        "Isolation": "",
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Memory": 0,
        "NanoCpus": 0,
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
        "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "Devices": null,
        "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
        "DeviceRequests": null,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "MemorySwappiness": null,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "PidsLimit": null,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "CpuCount": 0,
        "CpuPercent": 0,
        "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
        "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
        "MaskedPaths": [
            "/proc/asound",
            "/proc/acpi",
            "/proc/kcore",
            "/proc/keys",
            "/proc/latency_stats",
            "/proc/timer_list",
            "/proc/timer_stats",
            "/proc/sched_debug",
            "/proc/scsi",
            "/sys/firmware",
            "/sys/devices/virtual/powercap"
        ],
        "ReadonlyPaths": [
            "/proc/bus",
            "/proc/fs",
            "/proc/irq",
            "/proc/sys",
            "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
        ]
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Data": {
            "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d262be09b375fa45a9bfd9971999df32963b40d89a5e74135903587d1a3fd3a4-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/87ea8df341c17b7edde32cc80403c237fa479bb1be078762e7447cc18afa0da8/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/446bce7c94e4807838c8f3edf81e59affd5165e339808a6d49c260b21eeb5dd1/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c559607af1a5f87f79b0a0da47c70bcea539a8d7de11043ccace078836ceae01/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4745d65314116165101e2d1c3ee5b9b76f62c366b92ca14b4d2e4a9c2cac3f94/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/99c897e9a40f89075b0f6f1ac580432541c643ab128dab593ae383ecb8359800/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/17c53abbd9fb45bfa27d499e2f6556f8f6547adf73ec51e7ca14a2fb35b3fcc3/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6d691b5f2382b656390b293cd36d6d40414e726075208bd42a3de78c4c6127f9/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a50d6e60edd3620085790eb43af399af9d66c9c834998ce98d5f32c97030d42a/diff",
            "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d262be09b375fa45a9bfd9971999df32963b40d89a5e74135903587d1a3fd3a4/merged",
            "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d262be09b375fa45a9bfd9971999df32963b40d89a5e74135903587d1a3fd3a4/diff",
            "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d262be09b375fa45a9bfd9971999df32963b40d89a5e74135903587d1a3fd3a4/work"
        },
        "Name": "overlay2"
    },
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "volume",
            "Name": "607632fcf35a5718cfdda92fd4e0b159e0c905c52e5bcaac37da3fb269e2e156",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/607632fcf35a5718cfdda92fd4e0b159e0c905c52e5bcaac37da3fb269e2e156/_data",
            "Destination": "/var/lib/mysql",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        }
    ],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "037e43e31ace",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "3306/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password",
            "MYSQL_DATABASE=flarum",
            "MYSQL_USER=flarum_user",
            "MYSQL_PASSWORD=flarum_password",
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "GOSU_VERSION=1.17",
            "LANG=C.UTF-8",
            "MARIADB_VERSION=1:11.6.2+maria~ubu2404"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "mariadbd"
        ],
        "Image": "mariadb:latest",
        "Volumes": {
            "/var/lib/mysql": {}
        },
        "WorkingDir": "",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "docker-entrypoint.sh"
        ],
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {
            "org.opencontainers.image.authors": "MariaDB Community",
            "org.opencontainers.image.base.name": "docker.io/library/ubuntu:noble",
            "org.opencontainers.image.description": "MariaDB Database for relational SQL",
            "org.opencontainers.image.documentation": "https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/",
            "org.opencontainers.image.licenses": "GPL-2.0",
            "org.opencontainers.image.ref.name": "ubuntu",
            "org.opencontainers.image.source": "https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker",
            "org.opencontainers.image.title": "MariaDB Database",
            "org.opencontainers.image.url": "https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker",
            "org.opencontainers.image.vendor": "MariaDB Community",
            "org.opencontainers.image.version": "11.6.2"
        }
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "ba3a3c63bbf020efba4f635a86df3f44c9466ecc46b3b600ecff5503e14cc7ae",
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/ba3a3c63bbf0",
        "Ports": {
            "3306/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "3036"
                }
            ]
        },
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "2090245f434fc170b50e4ac90d8886f24c57aecb23770bb00e3e8014fb1a0fc3",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": null,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "DriverOpts": null,
                "NetworkID": "ca3b0138d767f7cc4262d6ee3e1223c8851c71beb01f2fa225fd4c63c5ba727a",
                "EndpointID": "2090245f434fc170b50e4ac90d8886f24c57aecb23770bb00e3e8014fb1a0fc3",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "DNSNames": null
            }
        }
    }
}

I WAS NEVER build a docker images with database before,so i was assume i could run the DB and config the  ENV like this so i don't need to edit the yaml file myself
, i was assume the docker desktop could done this for me ,but it couldn't connect ,am i wrong ?


flarum logs
2024-12-17 16:18:42 Checking database connection...
2024-12-17 16:18:42 Waiting 60s for database to be ready...
2024-12-17 16:23:01 ERROR: Failed to connect to database on flarum_db
2024-12-17 16:23:01 [cont-init.d] 03-config.sh: exited 1.
2024-12-17 16:23:01 [cont-finish.d] executing container finish scripts...
2024-12-17 16:23:01 [cont-finish.d] done.
2024-12-17 16:23:01 [s6-finish] waiting for services.
2024-12-17 16:23:02 [s6-finish] sending all processes the TERM signal.
2024-12-17 16:23:05 [s6-finish] sending all processes the KILL signal and exiting.



I am sure it didn't connect ,because the logs in mariaDB show no SIGNS of connection
so what went wrong?
update：
I have connect to MariaDB using docker compose
``
version: "3"
services:
flarum:
image: mondedie/flarum:stable
container_name: flarum
env_file:
- ./flarum.env
volumes:
- ./assets:/flarum/app/public/assets
- ./extensions:/flarum/app/extensions
- ./storage/logs:/flarum/app/storage/logs
- ./nginx:/etc/nginx/flarum
ports:
- "81:8888"
depends_on:
- mariadb
mariadb:
image: mariadb:10.5
container_name: mariadb
environment:
- MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password
- MYSQL_DATABASE=flarum
- MYSQL_USER=flarum
- MYSQL_PASSWORD=flarum_password
volumes:
- ./mysql/db:/var/lib/mysql
docker compose up -d


How are you starting the container(s)?  What's consuming these JSON-syntax environment variable blocks?  You say you're having trouble connecting to the database; is there an error message showing that?  It would be helpful if you could [edit] the question to include a [mcve], probably including at least something like a docker-compose.yml file and the actual error messages.

based on the PUID stuff this looks like LinuxServer which has the un(der)documented ENV DATADIR=/config/databases as the path for the database. Not sure how/why /data is being used (lack of documentation is a good reason). My biased recommendation is to use the docker official images of MariaDB that I maintain.

DB_HOST would need to match container name of flarumdb

i have connect my mariaDB using docker yaml file
version: "3"

services:
  flarum:
    image: mondedie/flarum:stable
    container_name: flarum
    env_file:
      - ./flarum.env
    volumes:
      - ./assets:/flarum/app/public/assets
      - ./extensions:/flarum/app/extensions
      - ./storage/logs:/flarum/app/storage/logs
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/flarum
    ports:
      - "81:8888"
    depends_on:
      - mariadb

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.5
    container_name: mariadb
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=flarum
      - MYSQL_USER=flarum
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=flarum_password
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/db:/var/lib/mysql

docker compose up -d
